# How find the indices of numbers picked for the maximum sum of non adjacent numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

I have come up with the algorithm for finding the maximum sum of non adjacent elements in an array, but I have some trouble finding which numbers are picked for the summation. Here is my algorithm for the max sum(without some initializations):

```
int n; //number of cells. Cells are labeled from 1 to n
int num[]; // all the numbers
int findMax[]; // findMax[i] equals to the current maximum score
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
    if (i == 0){
         findMax[0] = num[0];
    }
    else if (i == 1){
         findMax[1]= Math.max(findMax[0],num[1]);

    }
    else{
         findMax[i]=Math.max(findMax[i-2]+num[i], findMax[i-1]);

}
return findMax[n];
```

It is not so obvious for me to get the indice of the numbers we choose. Could someone give me any insights on this please? Thanks!

Comment: I am a new user in stack overflow community. If my question is not clear, please comment here. Any hints or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use own condition to get the best variant instead of `Math.max`.

When you choose max value from two variants, write the best variant index into some additional storage (array).

In the end unwind track of the best combination.

I hope this clue is enough to solve the task.